# Retrieve Value of RadioButton checked

Tags: android, radio-button, radio-group

Since several days, I search how to retrieve the checked radio Button ID, and after display the RadioButton checked in a Toast. But I get NULLPOINTER EXECEPTION for the int ID_LANGUE. I use this code :

```
enter code here
int ID_LANGUE = radioGroup_LANGUE.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                            RadioButton rb_L = (RadioButton)findViewById(ID_LANGUE);
                            if (rb_L.equals("Anglais")){
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Anglais",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
```

Comment: This is my XML : <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="148dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/RadioGroup_LANGUE">


     

    </RadioGroup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to get the radio group first by

```
 RadioGroup rg = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.RadioGroup_LANGUE);
```

Then you can use `setOnCheckedChangeListener` to determine which radio button was clicked actually.

```
rg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() 
        {
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                switch(checkedId){
                    case R.id.radio0:
                        //you selected radio0
                    break;    
                    case R.id.radio1:
                        //you selected radio1
                    break;  
                }
            }
        });
```

Other way is using `getCheckedRadioButtonId` also  `int id = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();` you get hold of selected radio id.

Comment: Thanks @Neel. I will try this. :)

Comment: Android Studio tell me to need be declared my alertdialog final. Because I execute your code in my alertdialog, when user click on button